# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is Hank Hanegraaff's "exegetical eschatology" hermeneutic original?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/is-hank-hanegraaffs-exegetical-eschatology-hermeneutic-original)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In 1 Timothy 1:5, what is the meaning of «τῆς παραγγελίας»?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7519/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-1-tim-15)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What was the authorial intent of Genesis 1?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-was-the-authorial-intent-of-genesis-1)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [1 Cor 12:22-25 — 'weaker'? 'less honorable'? 'unpresentable'?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/1-cor-1222-25-weaker-less-honorable-unpresentable)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Was or wasn’t Shem’s son Arphaxad born on the ark?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7422/was-or-wasnt-shems-son-arpachshad-born-on-the-ark)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [John 12:32 - What/Who Does the "All" refer to?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/john-1232-what-who-does-the-all-refer-to)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What would be a good translation of 'poiēma'?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/what-would-be-a-good-translation-of-poima)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [When does the first day of Genesis 1 begin?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/when-does-the-first-day-of-genesis-1-begin)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does the New Testament use the divine name "Yahweh"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/does-the-new-testament-use-the-divine-name-yahweh)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does chamushim ("fifties") mean in Exodus 13:18?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/what-does-chamushim-fifties-mean-in-exodus-1318)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 5):

One issue I noticed was that transliterated words are sometimes difficult to find in search. For instance, I was able to find [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/what-would-be-a-good-translation-of-poima) as the second result on Google for "poiēma", but a search for "poiema" didn't return it in the top two pages for me. Greek words that are not transliterated turned up our questions just fine. Not sure if we should consider editing questions to include both, or if it's better to just leave them however the original author wrote them.

Comment: I think we should leave the transliterated words in place (but if you wanted to change letters with accents to standard letters to aid in searches that is also probably fine), but perhaps also edit the Greek words in to help the OP (a lot of folks don't know how to type Greek and/or don't have Unicode resources). I don't think this should be a requirement of any kind, but a helpful edit along these lines should certainly be encouraged!